# Add content , if there is no error array below

Tags: php, arrays, include

This is my code:

```
$msg = "Hello User {$uid}";
echo $msg;
$action = $_GET['do'];

if( file_exists("page/actions/{$action}.php") && !empty($action))
    include_once("page/actions/{$action}.php");
else
    include_once("page/actions/default.php");
```

Now I need to change it into:

if included page :

```
include_once("page/actions/{$action}.php");
```

returned an 'error' array then `$msg` variable won't be displayed.

Is that possible?

Comment: Dude, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: How are you collecting the "error array"? Is there a variable that will/will not be set if this happens?

Comment: @MeLight
Read the question so you'll know.

Comment: @DaveRandom
As you can see, the `$msg` variable is above the include function, if it'll be below the function it'll be easy to check that, but the problem is that the `echo $msg;` is above. Hope you got it.

Comment: Please show the 'error' array ..

Comment: @AshokKS
'error' array contains an msg to show to the user.

Comment: I can't understand, if your program display error, please update with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand but if you set an error array in your included file you can check with `isset($errorArray)`. And echo the message if not set.

Comment: Yea, but `echo $msg`, need to be above the `include` function. , and this is the problem.

Comment: @Cyclone *Why* does it need to be above?

Comment: Then you can buffer the output. Then check if error array set. If yes clean the buffer. Otherwise print.

Comment: Put `ob_start()` at the beginning. If there is no error use `ob_flush` to send the buffered output. For more info look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php)